# Wait for a network queue to contain a specific element (Lamport's algorithm)?

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm

I want to wait for a network queue to contain a specific element before proceeding.

To be specific, I'm trying to implement Lamport's clock algorithm.

The element, I'd like to wait for is an acknowlegdement to a sent network message. The response can be put into the queue at any time, i.e. it may not be the first element in the queue. Therefore I cannot rely on `take()`.

Is the only solution to go over the queue repeatedly in a `while(true)` until the element is in the queue, or is there a better, more efficient, way?

Comment: what is a "network" queue actually?

Comment: Just a queue for network traffic. A normal Java queue.

Comment: I don't know how much I understood the requirements but while inserting in the queue, keep a check for desired response and as soon as you encounter the response generate a signal/interrupt to let you know.
Note: this could worsen the insertion time in queue.

Comment: Are you waiting for the acknowledgement because you want to be sure the message will be (or has been) delivered before proceeding? I.e. you're trying to implement some guaranteed delivery mechanism?